# m2eclipse: How do I configure parameters to the Maven Project Builder?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

In Eclipse Helios with m2eclipse installed, Build Automatically is on by default.  I can see that this uses some sort of incremental Maven builder under the covers (for Maven projects, obviously).

How can I customize the Maven builder so that, for example, I can supply it with some `-D` options?  Specifically, I want my automatic, incremental Maven builds to be run with `-Dmaven.buildNumber.doCheck=false`.  I see nowhere where I can actually affect the configuration of the m2eclipse-supplied Maven builder.

I am aware that I can create a run configuration and then explicitly build my project using Run As..., but I don't want to pursue that path.  I want to customize the way my project is built when I choose the Build All command from the Project menu.  I also want these customizations to be in effect when an automatic build is triggered.

I don't particularly want to add settings to my `~/.m2/settings.xml` file because I don't actually want my command-line Maven installation to pick up these settings outside of Eclipse.

Thanks in advance for any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you need to put the settings in a profile and then trigger that profile. The M2E gang has removed the settings that used to be useful for this purpose.

You can make a custom settings.xml in a separate location and configure THAT in the m2e prefs.

Comment: Thank you. I hope it's not too chicken-and-egg to ask how to trigger a profile that is only active when the Maven Builder is running?

Comment: There's a preference dialog in Eclipse that takes a list of profiles.

Comment: @bmargulies I can't find where per-project settings.xml have to be configured in that dialog. I'm looking where to put the "-s" CLI parameter. Thank you